# Warning: [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the movie data

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, mp4, batch-rename, exiftool

I typed the following command at a Windows 10 command prompt:

```
C:\hoge>"exiftool(-k).exe" "-FileName<CreateDate" -d "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%%e" C:\hoge
Warning: [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the movie data - C:/hoge/C0001.MP4
    1 directories scanned
    1 image files updated
-- press RETURN --
```

What does this warning mean?
How can I avoid warnings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning is informational only.  It is letting you know that you might not be seeing all the data that can be extracted from the file and to add the [`-ee` (extractEmbedded) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ee--extractEmbedded) to your command if you want to see all of it.  Things like GPS track data will not be shown without it because that content can be extensive.

You can safely ignore this warning and it can be suppressed by adding the [`-m` (ignoreMinorErrors) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#m--ignoreMinorErrors) option to your command.  This, however, will also suppress all other minor warnings.  Actual errors will still be reported.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The explanation was very easy to understand.